# Measure theory practice problems

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

Could anybody recommend any texts which have lots of practice problems for measure theory, in particular, integrating with respect to a measure.

I have always found that I understand conceptually the theory behind integrating with respect to a measure, but I have never been able to apply it to computations very well.

Thanks.

Comment: Most measures you will encounter will not be easy to integrate against, unless they are absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure, in which case the exercise will be the same as computing a standard (calculus) integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for textbooks suitable to a beginning graduate student, I would recommend all three of these textbooks

1. [Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471317160) by Gerald B. Folland.
2. [Real and Complex Analysis by Walter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070542341) by Walter Rudin.
3. [Introduction to Measure Theory](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-126) by Terence Tao. He also maintains lecture notes on his [blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/category/teaching/245a-real-analysis/).

I went through most of the first six chapters of Folland in my first course on measure theory. The exercises in this textbook are wonderful. Papa Rudin also has outstanding exercises.